# Sets and Functions (Discrete Math)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Prove that If 0 ⊆  and 1 ⊆ , then (0) − (1) ⊆ (0 − 1)

Prove that if 0 ⊆ , 1 ⊆  and  is one to one, then (0) − (1) = (0 − 1)

Comment: I have no idea how to start

Comment: Am i supposed to start by declaring arbitrary elements?

Comment: Sure, that would be a promising approach (we often call this an "element chasing" proof).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no idea how to start I'm going to give you a hint. Let $x\in f(A_0)-f(A_1)$ this means that $x\in f(A_0)$ and $x\notin f(A_1)$, so that there exists $y\in A_0$ such that $f(y)=x$ and $y\notin A_1$. From this reasoning you can see that your first statement holds. Write this more formally, and follow the same reasoning for the second statement.

Comment: How does this include that 1 ⊆ ?

Comment: @AnkithYennu that information is not relevant. Maybe $X$ is some defined "universe". If you see the thesis of each statement does not include $X$. It would be useful to define the function: $f: X\to S$, for example, so that it is guaranteed that every element $x\in X$ has an image under the function $f$.

Comment: I understand how you're using the arbitrary elements to show how y∉A1, how would you show that this represents (0 − 1)?

Comment: So I got the first part.  For the second part, I realized I have to prove (0 − 1) ⊆  (0) − (1) , so I started with y ∈ (0 − 1), where do I go from there and how is the one-to-one relationship useful in the proof?

Comment: @AnkithYennu I will have dinner and later on I will write more about this.

Comment: @AnkithYennu Note that if $y \in f(A_0 - A_1)$ then it follows that $y\in f(A_0)$. Now you have to prove that $y\notin f(A_1)$. This is done noting that if $y\in f(A_1)$ then there exists $x\in A_1$ and also $x' \in A_0 - A_1$ such that $y=f(x)=f(x')$. But this would mean that $f$ is not one-to-one. This is a contradiction and therefore $y\notin f(A_1)$, finishing the proof. As always, write this more formally.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this?

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXLeH.png)

Comment: This should be a comment, unless the answer is completely written here.

Also I think that you have done a good job.